# php: session not working while running live on server

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am working on a project of PHP. I have a strange error. My PHP project is working well on local server (WAMP server). But after hosting it on live server, it is not working.

**Problem:** Session variable created on `Login.php` page is not passing value on `Report.php` page. The code is as below:

**Login.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("mysql51****************","username","password")or die(mysql_error());
$select_db=mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);
$error="";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $userid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE user_name='{$userid}' AND password='{$password}' ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $error="Invalid UserId or Password.";
    }
    else
    {
        //session_set_cookie_params(60*60*60, '/', '.abcxyz.com');
        ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.abcxyz.com');
    session_start();
    //$userid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abc']);
    //echo($userid);
    $_SESSION['user']=$userid;
    $_SESSION['userid']="true";
    //echo $_SESSION['userid'];
    $error="Successfully Login";
    //header("Location: admin.php?page=report");
    /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("header is not working.' . $_SESSION['user'] . '");</script>';
*/  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*alert("Please select a Source And Destination Country");  */
        window.location.href='admin.php?page=report';
    </script>       
<?php

    }
}
?>

<br />

  <h1 style="text-align:center">Login</h1>
  <form  class="login"  action="login.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>Username:</p>
      <input class="login-input" type="text" name="username" value=""/>

    <p> Password : </p>
      <input class="login-input" type="password" name="password" value=""/>

  <p>
    <p style="color:#F00; font-size:12px; font-weight:100"><?php echo htmlentities($error); ?>  </p>
    <input  class="login-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>    
</form>
```

**Report.php**

```
<?php
include("connections/Connections.php");
/*$con=mysql_connect("localhost","admin","")or die(mysql_error());
$select_db=mysql_select_db("test",$con);*/
/*session_start();
if(session_is_registered('test'))
{
    echo"registered";
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}*/

//$user=$_SESSION['userid'];

$user=$_SESSION['userid'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("header is not working.' .$user . '");</script>';
if($user=="true")
{
    //echo " Logining Successfully.";
}
else
{
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //alert("Please select a Source And Destination Country");  
        window.location.href='login.php';
    </script>
<?php
    //header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
<?php
/*session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['userid'];
echo($user);
if($user=="Admin")
{
    echo " Logining Successfully.";*/

$sql="SELECT * FROM register ";
if(isset($_POST['btnfilter']))
{
    $search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_text']);
    $answer = $_POST['filter'];  
    if ($answer == "ID") {          
        $sql .="WHERE id= '{$search_term}' ";
    }
    elseif ($answer == "Name") {          
        $sql .="WHERE fullname Like '%{$search_term}%'";
    }
    elseif ($answer == "DOB") {          
        $sql .="WHERE dob Like '%{$search_term}%' ";
    }
    elseif ($answer == "Occupation") {          
        $sql .="WHERE occupation Like '%{$search_term}%' ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo("Pealse Enter a valid value"); 
    }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['btnrmfilter']))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM register";
}

$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_errno());
//}
/*else
{
    header('Location: /login.php');
}*/
?>

<style type="text/css">
    table
    {
        font-size:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc}
    td 
    { 
    padding:5px 3px;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc}
</style>

  <div class="content">
  <h1>Data Reading From database.</h1>
  <form id="search_form" method="post" action="">
  <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="filter" value="ID" />ID
      <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Name" />Name
      <input type="radio" name="filter" value="DOB"/>DOB
      <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Occupation"/>Occupation<br />
  </div>
  <div class="input" >
      <input   type="text" name="search_text" value=""/>
      <input  type="submit" value="FilterData" name="btnfilter" />     
      <input  type="submit" value="RemoveFilter" name="btnrmfilter" />
  </div>
  </form>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <colgroup> 
    <col width="2%" style="color:#f60" valign="middle" align="center" >
    <col width="12%" >
    <col width="8%" >
    <col width="5%" align="center" >
    <col width="10%" >

    </colgroup>
      <tr style="background:#eee; height:30px;">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Nationality</td>
        <td>Mobile No</td>
        <td>Phone No</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Education</td>
        <td>Occupation</td>
        <td>Comment</td>
        <td >Noofexp</td>
      </tr>

        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
          <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['dob']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['nationality']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['mobno']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['phno']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['education']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['occupation']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['noofexp']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <h3>Thanks for view.</h3>

    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>

<!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

As the answers suggested, i edited as below:

**Login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("mysql51*************","username","password")or die(mysql_error());...
...
```

**Report.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connections/Connections.php");...
...
```

But still i am not getting the session variable value in `Report.php`.

Comment: You're not calling `session_start()` in `Report.php`

Comment: error reporting? and also u need to state which hosting u using windows/linux?

Answer (score 2):

`session_start();` should be placed on top of the both pages.

Comment: have you checked your phpinfo() ?

Comment: Yes I have checked it.Session Support - enabled

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar is it windows hosting? please also check the `session.save_path` in `php.ini` and check the path is exists or `echo ini_get('session.save_path');`

Comment: yes i checked a session.save_path and i am not getting proper path on server.but i don't no how to give a server path and store session on server.so if you have idea to store session on server folder so please help me.

Comment: What output did you get from `session_path` is the directory exsits?

Comment: /var/bin/php/tmp this path i got in a output.which is not exist on my server

Comment: Is it window hosting or linux environment?

Comment: it is windows hosting.

Comment: wait for others answers than :)

Answer (score 0):

You must add `session_start();` in your report.php page

Comment: no i am not getting any error.just i am not getting session variable value on report.php.and that value i am checking also by the alert as you can see in my code.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your phpinfo() ?
make shure you have
Session Support  - enabled

Comment: Yes I have checked it.Session Support - enabled

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on your WAMP successfully, It is very possible that the problem is not from your code but from your hosting company.

Something like this happened to me before.

Just call you hosting company and tell them to enable session on their server for you and they will it for you.

and always start session first before any script just as you did above.

```
  session_start();
```

Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

Go try adding this on your code:

```
if(!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect:'. mysql_error());
    }
```

and see what the error is.

Comment: sorry friend but connection does not have any problem.it is working .

Comment: Oh, i see... Didn't see that part. O.O

Answer (score -1):

very easy solve to this problem copy this code

```
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
```

Note: give space from left side of `session_start();` if you want understand about this watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmr1NXOz_pk)